How to pass selected record Ids from related list to flow URL?
I created a custom button in related list in salesforce.
Using ids I tried to retrieve the selected records but nothing is retrieving back

Did you make sure to set ids to Available for input?

Creating ids Variable
First things first, I need to introduce you to the variable “ids”. ids variable is a Salesforce system variable, which allows you to pass multiple record ids into it. I will show you later how simple it is to use it, but first, some considerations about ids variable
ids variable is case sensitive. Do not use “Ids”, “IDS” or “IDs”. It will not work; it should be all lowercase.
When Salesforce passes values to the ids variable, they are separated by a comma. To avoid complicated extraction of record ids from text variables use the Collection Variable type of variable in the flow (we’ll get back to this in a while).
You can see more details here https://www.accidentalcodersf.com/2023/02/flow-list-view-pass-records.html
